# MVC & RewriteRule isn't working at all

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I have built a website with a homemade MVC structure and pretty urls with .htaccess aren't working at all.
I have this "front controller" (`index.php`) at the root of my website :

```
<?php
require_once('M/connect_sql.php');

if (!empty($_GET['page']) && is_file('C/'.$_GET['page'].'.php'))
{
    include 'C/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
}
else
{
    include 'C/accueil.php';
}

$bdd = NULL;
```

`C/` is my controller folder.

Example of my urls :
http://domain.com/?page=restaurants&city=paris&CP=75001

`page` parameter is for my controller and `&city=paris&CP=75001` are POST variables.

I have tested a simple rewrite rule out of MVC and it works well. 
I tried several Rewrite rules but none are working.

Here's an example for the URL above :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.+/)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /?page=$1&city=$2&CP=$3 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have placed an `.htaccess` in every folder (root, controller, views), but I can't get it.

EDIT SINCE RESPONSE :

Here's my new controller since Entwicklerpages notice a security hole. Found this solution here : http://kkovacs.eu/exploiting-web-development-worst-practices-file-inclusion

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['page']) and ! is_null($_REQUEST['page']) )
{
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
switch ($page) {
  case 'restaurant':
    include('C/restaurant.php');
    break;
  case 'restaurants':
    include('C/restaurants.php');
    break;

    }
}
else {
    include('C/accueil.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware of the security hole in your implementation!
It is never a good idea to let the user decide which php files are included.

```
include 'C/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
```

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion

Also, a second idea from my site.
The `$_SERVER` Variable in PHP have a field called PATH_INFO

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

If your site is called as index.php/your/params/and/other/data

You can split it by the '/' and get all your data.
Also this may be a little easier to make it fancy with ModRewrite

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I use this at my own site: http://www.entwicklerpages.de/Startseite.html (German)

Comment: Thanks a lot Entwicklerpages for the time you took to respond. It really helps ! I managed to make RewriteRule. For the security hole, i have updated my post with the solution i found. Do you think it's safer now ?